# How can I put a shapefile into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, shapefile

Trying to update my companies census data. I need GEOID, population, and latitude and longitude. I spoke to someone affiliated with census.gov and was pointed towards two downloads, one that had GEOID and population for states, one that has GEOID and lat + long for states. She said I would have to import both and join on GEOID. The first one was an excel file, so easy to import into SQL. However, the one with lat + long only comes as a .shp (shapefile). I've been really struggling trying to figure out a way to get this data into SQL from the shapefile. Does anyone know a way?

I tried different ways to import from within SQL to no avail, also looked online and it seems like it is possible but I couldn't find anything recent enough to help me.

Comment: What's the database? If it's java based (HyperSQL, H2, Derby) long time back I wrote the [ESRI Shape File Reader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javashapefilere/) library in Java. A simple adapter in H2 could be used to read the lat/long values into a table-like structure. Otherwise you could use the library to extract lat/long to CSV and then load the CSV in H2 separately. The latter solution seems simpler to me.